# Which features can I try to extract out of mp3 files to classify them?

Tags: audio, machine-learning, classification, feature-extraction

I am planning to build a music genre classifier working with mp3 files, and I wanna test and see which features work best for this. I have seen a paper that used MFCC(Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients) for this, but as a beginner in Machine Learning, this method felt complicated. I also saw some that converted mp3 files into spectograms and analysed those, but with no success. What I am looking for is a few easy-to-extract features to classify mp3 files. Do any other methods exist save for the two I just listed?

Comment: if you want "easy", just pull the 'genre' field out of the ID3 tags...

Comment: The files I am analyzing do not contain any data in the genre field.

Answer (score 0):

There are some papers on this, you can easily google them up.

But the simplest features would be the beat speed, the proportions of high/low frequencies etc.

All of this can be extracted using FFT (Fast Fourier Transform). But I am afraid this may not be so easy if you haven't done it before...